# over partion in sum is not working mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

getting the error

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY th_class_4, th_class_3,
>   th_class_2, th_class_1 )  ,t2.QTY AS QTY f' at line 2

```
select t1.PROD_NM as PROD_NM,t1.TherapeuticClass as TherapeuticClass,
         t1.MFG as MFG,round(t2.TOTAL,2),SUM(t2.TOTAL)OVER(PARTITION BY th_class_4, th_class_3, th_class_2, th_class_1 )
         ,t2.QTY AS QTY from
         (select PROD_NM,concat(TH_CLASS_1,",",TH_CLASS_2,",",TH_CLASS_3,",",TH_CLASS_4)
         as TherapeuticClass,MFG from RETAIL_STORE_PROD
         where TH_CLASS_1!='NULL' and TH_CLASS_2!='NULL' and TH_CLASS_3!='NULL'
         and TH_CLASS_4!='NULL')t1

join

    (select PROD_NM,sum(TOTAL) AS TOTAL,sum(QTY) AS QTY from RETAIL_STR_SALES_DETAIL
    group by PROD_NM)t2 on t1.PROD_NM=t2.PROD_NM
```

Comment: Window functions were added in MySQL 8.  What version are you using?

Comment: Windowed functions don't appear in MySQL version <8

Comment: yes it is mysql 8

Comment: is there is any other way

Comment: any example will appreciable

Comment: The manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html has examples. If you are having difficulty applying the principals to your situation try adding sample data and expected output to your question as text and no doubt someone will get on it.

Comment: You don't select those th_class_* fields in the sub-queries? Then how should the outer query get them if you want to use them in that window function of SUM?

Comment: I am not convinced that you are using MySQL 8. The error message is exactly the error your get if your version does not support window functions. Using e.g. MySQL Workbench 8 does not mean you are using MySQL 8. Or you might be connected to a different server that you expect. So before your keep trying to figure out what is wrong with your code, try `select @@version;` to make sure you have the right version.

Comment: yaa i checked it again its not mysql version 8 i am think of other way out if any approach it will be appreciable